# Windows 10 - How to Navigate Nested Apps on Taskbar with Keyboard?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, taskbar

I know that one can use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to navigate through all the apps on the taskbar via the arrow keys, from left to right.

And I know that a faster method is to use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>0-9</kbd> to instantly access the apps in numbered order from left to right (first 1-9, and then 0 for the last one).

But when using e.g. <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> to access Windows Explorer with **nested** instances (= multiple folders open), I can't seem to use my arrow keys to navigate through the nested folders. I've tried almost all key combinations and it doesn't work -- either it closes or selects the first folder only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to **press the same key combination again** to browse through all the nested/grouped app instances.

E.g. if you press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> to select Windows Explorer, then press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> *again* to get to the next folder on the right.

If you want to go *left*, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>

[image: Video showcasing usage of Win+2 and Shift+Win+2 keyboard shortcuts]